# Different behaviour with windows authentication on IIS7 websites

Tags: authentication, iis7, localhost, windows-7, 401

I need to run a website with just windows authentication. 
Given the following situation:

- The location of the default website is: c:\inetpub\wwwroot
- The location of my code is: c:\Sites\WebApp
- My hostfile is edited so any .local i use points to 127.0.0.1
- I am using Windows 7 professional
- IIS version: 7.5

I have created a new application called 'AppX' underneath the default website and point it to c:\Sites\WebApp. It will use the DefaultappPool. When I switch off anonymous and switch on windows authentication all works well when I go to localhost/AppX/.

What I really want is a new website (No need to question why I want this). So I created a 2nd website and did exact the same creation of the application. Everything is the same; destination, app pool and authentication.

Now when I browse to this website web2.local/AppX/ I get the 401.2 - Unauthorized error.
What am I missing here?

UPDATE: I also tried to create a new website directly pointing to the target folder. Same settings for authentication, applicationpool, etc. Same result as using an application in a new website.

Comment: To start I suggest checking access right on `c:\inetpub\wwwroot` folder and compare to the root folder for `web2.local` (even despite the fact that actual app is located in different folder).

Comment: I tried both. using %SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot as destination for web2 and a different folder. Same result for both.

Comment: Can you just clarify which OS you're doing this on, win7 or windows server 2k8?

Comment: Just added them to the list.